# Change the tint of an emoji in an EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

Is it possible to force the tint color of emojis on an `EditText` or `TextView` in Android?
I would like to have a white color in an EditText when the user enter a text and a white/grey tint for the emojis.

With the attribute `textColor` it only change the color of the text but when the user put an emojis, the emoji is colored.

I would like something like this :
[image]

Maybe it's possible with a `tint` parametre but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: are you using https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/emoji/widget/EmojiTextView.html ?

Comment: AFAIK, emojis cannot be colored like any normal font.

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu no i'm just using an `EditText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply impossible to do.
Emojis cannot be colored like any normal font.

Answer (score 0):

Not like normal fonts, but Emojis can be colored!

This example makes the Emojis grey:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.etTestEmoji);
ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
matrix.setSaturation(0f);
ColorMatrixColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
TextPaint textPaint = editText.getPaint();
textPaint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
```